# How to create sklearn random forest model identical to R randomForest?

Tags: r, classification, forecasting, data-mining, python

In R I usually define Random Forest as follows (an example):

```
rf <- randomForest(train[,features], 
                   train$Y,
                   mtry=5,
                   ntree=15,
                   sampsize=50000,
                   do.trace=TRUE)
```

Now I started learning Python and I wonder how to set the same model with same tuning parameters in Python? I know about `sklearn RandomForestClassifier`, but it seems to be defined with a very different set of parameters.

Comment: you probably will get more attention by posting such question on Stack Overflow

Comment: @Soren Havelund Welling: Thank you, Posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32976208/how-to-create-sklearn-random-forest-model-identical-to-r-randomforest